# How to get standard Android 4.1 ProgressBar Layout?

Tags: java, android

I am just wondering, why i dont get the standard Android 4.1 ProgressBar Layout. In my AndroidManifest.xml i define

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.wucop.quiz3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

    ...

</manifest>
```

and the ProgressBar like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_sq_white" >

    ...

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_list_item_level"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_list_item_level_title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv_list_item_go"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_list_item_level_title"
        android:max="100" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But i just gettig the Android 2.3.3 layout (http://p07.imgup.net/Screenshotafb3.png).

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: What are you using for your theme in your manifest?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it... updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specifically told Android to use the pre-Holo theme (`Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`). If you want to use the holographic widget theme, you need to use something rooted in `Theme.Holo` on API Level 11+.

Comment: Well... it was really that easy. Thanks for your help!